# sorting keys of a dictionary with lowercase letters, uppercase letters and numbers

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort the keys of a dictionary first by numbers then lowercase letters and then uppercase letter 
and return it back in a dictionary with the correct value for the key. 
I came up with this, but in my opinion this is too long. (board is the given dictionary you want to sort) 
board example :

```
board = {
  (3, 4) : 0,
  ("a", 4) : 0,
  (1, 3)  :  0,
  ("X", 5) : 5,
  ("X", 1) : 1
}
```

My question is if it is possible to shorten the code.

```
x = []
y = []
for k in dict.keys(board):
    if str(k[0]).islower():
        list.append(x, (k, board[k]))
for k in dict.keys(board):
    if k[0] == "X":
        list.append(y, (k, board[k]))
for k in range(0, len(x)):
    del board[x[k][0]]
for k in range(0, len(y)):
    del board[y[k][0]]
x = sorted(x)
y = sorted(y)
for k in range(0, len(x)):
    board[x[k][0]] = x[k][1]
for k in range(0, len(y)):
    board[y[k][0]] = y[k][1]
```

Comment: Is everything a `str`? could please provide the expected minimum reproducible example

Comment: What is the question? ... https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: See, that dictionary has `tuple`s as keys, So that raises the question: The second element on the tuple mater? If both keys are the same should be sorted according to the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following sort based in desired order but based upon the key tuple.

Thus ('X', 1) should be before ('X', 5) because first elements are equal so depends on second element.

**Sort Routine**

```
def sort_dict(d):
  def ordering(i):
    """Create ordering so that numbers are before strings
       lowercase strings are before upper case strings"""
    return ([isinstance(i, int), isinstance(i, str) and i.islower(), isinstance(i, str) and i.isupper()].index(True), i)

  # By applying ordering to all elements of key, we create a new tuple
  # which allows us to compare
  return dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: tuple(map(ordering, kv[0]))))
```

**Test**

```
board =  {(3,4):0,("a",4):0,(1,3):0,("X",5):5,("X",1):1}
print(sort_dict(board))
```

**Output**

```
{(1, 3): 0, (3, 4): 0, ('a', 4): 0, ('X', 1): 1, ('X', 5): 5}
```

Comment: I like this solution. But it is hard to read since I have not encountered this pattern before. I had to run the code locally through a debugger to understand it. I think it could be made clearer by using 'value' as the parameter name to ordering, i makes me think of index.  And splitting up the return statement to two lines in ordering as well maybe? When reading a solution in the browser the `.index(True)` part is not visible without sideways scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe do something like this:

```
result = {}
for x in sorted(filter(lambda x: type(x[0]) == int, board.keys())):
  result[x] = board[x]

for x in sorted(filter(lambda x: type(x[0]) == str, board.keys()), key=lambda x: x[0].islower(), reverse=True):
  result[x] = board[x]

>>> result
{(1, 3): 0, (3, 4): 0, ('a', 4): 0, ('X', 5): 5, ('X', 1): 1}
```

Also, just in case if you wanted to have uppercase letters before lowercase and if the numbers were only 1 digit long then you could have used [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to sort them

```
>>>sorted(board.keys(), key=lambda x: ord(str(x[0])) if type(x[0]) == int else ord(x[0]))
[(1, 3), (3, 4), ('X', 5), ('X', 1), ('a', 4)]
```